# How can I reply a picture and count users on telegram bot?

Tags: php

I wanted to made a telegram bot so I started coding and this is what I have so far:

```html
<?php
$string = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    
    function objectToArray( $object )
    {
        if($text == 'Hi')
          $text_reply = 'Hi';
        if($text == 'What is you'r name?)
          $text_reply = 'testbot';
        if($text == 'How are you ?')
           $text_reply = 'Fine,Thanks';
    }
 
    $token = '';
    $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$token.'/sendMessage?chat_id='.$user_id;
    $url .= '&text=' .$text_reply;
    $res = file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

I didn't try it before but it's very simple and I think it will work.

1. How can I reply a photo from a URL ( someone ask it before but i want it in php) ?
2. How can I count users or save their ID in a database ? ( ex : when a user send /statics command if id=x reply members number ( when anyone send /start +1 to members number . else reply x )

Comment: What is that code snippet of yours supposed to do? What do you mean by 'reply a photo'? And for that user question, you'll need to provide some extra context as well. At the moment it isn't very clear what exactly you are asking and where you are stuck...